# How do you compile Kotlin source files dynamically/programmatically?

Tags: kotlin

I have some tests where I generate some Kotlin source files (via kotlin-poet) and I want to dynamically compile, load, and create instances of them in the tests.  I have been unable to find examples of how to do this online, so I am hoping someone here has that experience to share.

Comment: I don't recommend this strategy.  Generate the code, compile the generated code _statically,_ test that.